# wpf ComboBox Selected Item Displaying different text then item in drop down

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` that has a list of colors that the user can pick from. When the user clicks on a list of colors with the colors name and a small picture of the color is displayed for each item.  This part works correctly.  The part I can't get to work is once a item has been selected, for example if the user choses red, the `ComboBox` will say "Color[Red]" where I just want it to display Red.

XAML

```
<ComboBox x:Name="mycbox" IsEditable="True" Background="#FFE5E5E5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,133,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="82">      
     <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Name}" Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0,2,5,2"/>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
              </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
       </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>                                
 </ComboBox>
```

Code Behind

```
private List<Color> colors = new List<Color>() {  Red, Green, Blue, Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, Orange, Purple};

mycbox.ItemSource = colors;
```

[Here is an example of what my combo box items look like, to use as a reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpqpH.png)

Comment: sorry @mm8 it should be Color not Colors.

Comment: And why are you binding a Rectangle's Fill and a TextBlock's Text to the same Name property? That doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: I am doing that so each item has the name of the color and then a little square of the actual color next to it.

Comment: Seems to be `System.Drawing.Color`, which has a Name property. You shouldn't use that in WPF.

Comment: It's rather System.Windows.Media.Color. Its WPF

Comment: @walkerbox That's what OP *should* be using. However, he uses System.Drawing.Color. Otherwise `{Binding Name}` wouldn't work.

Comment: To Get back to my original question, how can I get the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` to  just "Red" and not "Color[Red]".

Comment: Use `SelectedValuePath="Name"` and `SelectedValue` instead of `SelectedItem`. However, your approach is still bad. Don't use System.Drawing (i.e. WinForms) types in a WPF app. `Fill="{Binding Name}"` may not work for all colors, because it relies on built-in automatic type conversion from string to `Brush`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I get the ComboBox.SelectedItem to just "Red" and not "Color[Red]"?

Set the `TextSearch.TextPath` property of the `ComboBox` to "Name".

```
<ComboBox x:Name="mycbox" IsEditable="True" 
          TextSearch.TextPath="Name" 
          Background="#FFE5E5E5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="82">
```